# Child class Keys.onPressed and MouseArea.onClicked

Tags: qt, qml

I have a base window which I want to reuse. The base window has some keyboard handling.

```
ApplicationWindow
{
  id: base
  visible: true
  width: 600
  height: 400

  Item
  {
    id: baseitem
    anchors.fill: parent
    focus: true

    Keys.onPressed:
    {
        console.log("base key: " + event.key)
        event.accepted = true
        // if (event.key === Qt.Key_Escape) {...}
    }

    MouseArea
    {
        id: basemousearea
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked:
        {
            console.log("base basemousearea clicked")
        }
    }
  }
}
```

On reusing this base window I want to add more keyboard handling. For example the base window should only deal with Esc and Return whereas the reuse window should deal with some other keys. However, this doesn't work. It's always only the base window's Keys.onPressed that is being executed. It also doesn't matter whether I set event.accepted to true or false. (Just out of curiosity and for comparison I also added mouse handling. Here the situation is the opposite - only the reuse window's MouseArea.onClicked is being executed but never that of the base window.) How do I go about getting both the base window's and the reuse window's Keys.onPressed executed?

This is the code of the reuse window:

```
Basewindow
{
  id: main

  Item
  {
    anchors.fill: parent
    focus: true

    Keys.onPressed:
    {
        console.log("main key: " + event.key)
        event.accepted = true
        // if (event.key === Qt.Key_F3) {...}
    }

    MouseArea
    {
        id: mainmousearea
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked:
        {
            console.log("main mainmousearea clicked")
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `Keys` is a kind of singleton so it's doesn't matter where do you place it. The only limitation that it is attached property of `Item` so you have to place `Keys` handlers inside `Item`-derived items. `ApplicationWindow` is not `Item`. Also don't forget to set `focus: true` to the item.

Comment: Both my base window and the reuse window have an Item and it is inside this that the Keys.onPressed are placed as you can see in my code.

Comment: one of them is out of focus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the only focused `Item` can receive the key event you have to set `focus: true` to the item. You can manage the event by accepting it or by forwarding the event to another item using `Keys.forwardTo: []`. For example:

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Window 2.2 

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 400

    Item {
        id: item1
        anchors.fill: parent
        Keys.onPressed: {
            console.log("Main: " + event.key);
            item2.focus = true;
        }
        focus: true
        Keys.forwardTo: [item2 ]
    }
    Sub {
        id: item2
        onChange: {
            item1.focus = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Sub.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.11

Item {
    signal change()   
    Keys.onPressed: {
        console.log("Sub: " + event.key);
        change();
    }
}
```

See [Key Handling Priorities](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-keys.html#key-handling-priorities) for more info.